# How to perform an action after a moving UIImage reaches a specific point

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage, int

i am trying out a pong game to start out developing games on the the iphone and i've got everything moving but i need to implement the scoring and make the ball return to the center of the screen
this is the code i have currently in the touchesBegan method:

```
    if(ball.center.y >=444) {
      computerScore=computerScore+1;
      computerScoreLabel=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", computer];
      ball.center.x=151;
      ball.center.y=222;
}

    if(ball.center.y <=4) {
      playerScore=playerScore+1;
      playerScoreLabel=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", player];
      ball.center.x=151;
      ball.center.y=222;
     }
```

it builds correctly and runs, but when i try the game on the simulator it just makes the ball move around and when it passes the specific points it just bounces off and the score doesn't change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you add an NSLog() statement so you can actually monitor the value of ball.center.y and see if it's, for instance, triggering a collision-bounce before the value actually matches your conditional.